# Перевод string в integer

Tags: c++

Подскажите пожалуйста функции для перевода типа string в integer в с++
Вот пример, собственно надо в N загнать число из S

```
#include <string>
int main()
{ 
    string S="74";
    int N;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

n = atoi(S.c_str());
```

Comment: Не проверял, но atoi() вроде принимает не string, а char*
поэтому n = atoi(S.c_str());

Comment: Да, действительно.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Долго ломал голову и гуглил. А можешь пару коментов дать к параметрам функции этой?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: ВНИМАНИЕ!!! Способ устарел, сейчас (2018) лучше использовать [**stoi**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/).

Comment: И чтобы не надо было вчитываться в документацию, замечу,  `stoi` использует `strtol` со всеми ее фичами

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {

    string S = "74";
    istringstream iss (S, istringstream::in);

    int val;
    iss >> val;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main(){
    string str = "1234567890";
    int num = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){     
        num = num*10 + str[i] - 0x30;   
    }
    cout << num;    
}
```

Comment: int num = NULL; ??????

Comment: оно работать будет, но да, выглядит дико. Но точка с запятой после include - это интересно.

Comment: сделай так, если страшно: int num = 0;

Comment: можно написать по всякому, но лучше писать так, как принято. Но в 2016 году лучше использовать [std::stoi](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/).

Comment: это сильно просто:

Answer (score 2):

```
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    string S = "74";
    int N = stoi (S);
}
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]