# Перевод строкового типа данных std:string в числа и обратно

Tags: c++, строки

Я знаю как соединить строки, копировать, удалить фрагмент и т.д.

Как перевести из числа в строку и обратно?

Как перевести массив char я знаю.

Comment: Под "строкой" тут подразумевается "std::string"?

Comment: да, строковый тип данных std:string

Comment: [из строки в число](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol), [из числа в строку](https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

Comment: @acade ответы — в ответы

Comment: Возможный дубликат: [Перевод string в integer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12292/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-string-%d0%b2-integer), [Преобразование типов в с++. Из int в string](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/687242/Преобразование-типов-в-с-Из-int-в-string)