# Как конвертировать элемент строки в int?

Tags: c++

использую код:

```
for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
    cout<<stoi(s1[i]) + stoi(s1[i-1]); //ошибка error: no matching function for call to 'stoi(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type&)'|
}
```

в чем проблема и как исправить? строка только из чисел.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12292/Перевод-string-в-integer уже был похожий вопрос

Comment: Какого типа массив `s1`?

Comment: `atoi` функция есть для перевода

Comment: @joystick: Функция `atoi` уже двадцать лет как не предназначена для практического использования ни в С, ни в С++, Она существует только для обратной совместимости. Забудьте об `atoi`.

Comment: @AnT хорошо, что тогда можно использовать вместо atoi?

Comment: @shumik_UA: В стандартной библиотеке С еще в 1995 году функции `ato...` были "поглощены" ("subsumed") функциями `strto...`. Для целых чисел - это `strtol`, `strtoul` и т.д. Именно ими и нужно пользоваться. Функции `ato...` - бессмысленные и бесполезные функции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что я пытался по очереди конвертировать символ (цифру) функцией из строки в инт, НО один символ - это  не строка а char. Задачу решил

Answer (score 0):

У вас, по-видимому, строка. Строка состоит не из "чисел", а из *цифр*. Цифры переводятся в соответствующие числовые значения при помощи выражения `s[i] - '0'`.

Если это не то, что вам нужно, то позаботьтесь о более-менее понятном описании задачи. Бессмысленного "строка только из чисел" - не достаточно.